# How to add button dynamically on panel which is created dynamically?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a panel dynamically. How can create a button dynamically on panel which is created dynamically in WPF?

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
Dim MyButtonUC As buttons_UC
Dim MyPanelUC As panels_UC

    Dim catname As String = InputBox("Please enter  category name here")
    Dim MyButtonUC = New Button

    MyButtonUC.Name = "btn" & catname.Replace(" ", "_").ToString
    MyButtonUC.Content = catname
    MyButtonUC.FontSize = 15
    MyButtonUC.Height = 40
    MyButtonUC.Width = 250
    MyButtonUC.Margin = New Thickness(0, 3, 0, 0)

    pnlCategoryButtonCont.Children.Add(MyButtonUC)

    Dim MyPanelUC As New WrapPanel
    MyPanelUC.Background = Brushes.Blue
    MyPanelUC.Name = "pnl" & catname.Replace(" ", "_").ToString
    pnlCategoryPnlContainer.Children.Add(MyPanelUC)

End Sub
```

In this above example I have created a button on any panel and also created a panel(A) on another panel. Now I want to add some buttons on panel(A) dynamically. Since the panel(A) is created dynamically, I could not call this directly, either i have to call this by using string, so that I can add Button on its as a children.

Comment: You have added a new Button to the `pnlCategoryButtonCont` panel and a new panel (`MyPanelUC`) to `pnlCategoryPnlContainer`. Which one would be `panel(A)`? Do you want to add Buttons to `MyPanelUC`? Declared it as a Field or find it by name (or any other property that allows you to single it out).

Comment: Hi Jimi, yes i want to add a button on (MyPanelUc). Can you help out to write code? In another way I have panel name as a string, how can i add button on this panel? In windows form we generally do Controls("panelName"). Add(btn)

Comment: In WPF you do it in a totally different way - with binding. See: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/. Instead of ListView you can use ItemsControl. Don't go the WinForms way- you'll only get to bigger and bigger troubles.

Comment: The above written code is working perfectly. I just want to add a button on panel created at last in this code. Since I'm new to this WPF, I would really appreciate you if you can write that piece of code as i did not get understanding of code you refer through link.

Comment: WinForms style: `myPanelUc.Children.Add(New Button() With {.Content = "Button2"})`. With this form, `myPanelUc` must be declared as a Field.

Comment: Hi Jimi, Thanks! thats worked perfectly. I have little trouble here. Since i have added these buttons on wrap panels and all these panels were added on dock panel. Wrap panels are not overlapping to each other on dock panel as soon I add any button on the wrap panels (they are just button area of backward panel). My expectation is when i click on category button it should bring the wrap panel of that category on front.